# Html codes working in editor ckeditor

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor with syntaxhighlighter. When i add html code, it's working in editor after submit.

**So, i am write this;**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
    <meta chrset="UTF 8">
    <title>test</title>     
</head>  
<body ng-app="app">
<h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{message}}</h1>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<script>  
    angular.module("app", []).controller("HelloWorldCtrl", function($scope) {  
    $scope.message="Hello World" 
    } )
</script> 

</body>  
</html>
```

**After submit return this in editor;**

```
{{message}}
```

How can i solve ? thankyou.

Comment: Everything looks fine and works when I copy/paste that into jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. Here is working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta chrset="UTF 8">
      <title>test</title>
       <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="app">
      <h1 ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{message}}</h1>
      <script>  
         var app = angular.module("app", []);
         app.controller("HelloWorldCtrl", function($scope) {  
             $scope.message="Hello World" 
         } )
      </script> 
   </body>
</html>
```